# getting all elements after a certain element, including their children

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to write some dynamic code and i can't be sure the element i'm after is sibling or child of a sibling.
i just have a class and must search for the first element that has this class after my element.
example:

```
   <something class='EitherMe'/>

   <table>
     <thead class = 'EitherMe'></thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr class = 'selectAfterThis'><td></td></tr>
        .
        .
        .
     </tbody>
     <tfoot class ='EitherMe'>
       <tr></tr>
       <tr class='OrMe'></tr>
     </tfoot>
   </table>

   <something class='OrMe'/>
```

i'll get 'EitherMe' or 'OrMe' depending on the user's need. and i need to select exactly the element with that class that comes after 'selectAfterThis'

nextAll() doesn't work. since it only gets the siblings.
is there any way to do this?

update: i put the thead in the above example.since most suggestion were going through the parent. and i don't really know if there is no element with class higher up.
i could limit my plugin by limiting the class's exact location but i want to avoid that if possible.

update2: simply put, i need the element with the specified class, that comes below 'selectAfterThis', whether its just below him, or far below him, or its parent-child relationship with 'selectAfterThis' doesn't matter

update 3: here's a mini plugin i wrote from wirey's answer. hope it helps anyone else who has a problem like me: http://jsfiddle.net/jTLt2/4/ . all credits go to wirey. i just did a few modifications to make it go deeper than just parent sibling and child of parents siblings.

please let me know if you test it. i want to know if it works 100%

here's the code :

```
(function($){
    $.fn.nextInView = function(selector)
    {
        var ret = this.nextAll(selector);      
        for(var i = 0;this.parents().eq(i).find('body').length < 1 ;i++){
            ret = ret.add(this.parents().eq(i).nextAll(selector));  
            ret = ret.add(this.parents().eq(i).nextAll().find(selector));
        }            
        return ret.first();
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: where is the starting point?  What is the context?

Comment: let me do an update, if possible i want to avoid going through the parent. since there might another element with that class for example in the <thead> in the above example. although the chances are slim.

Comment: Ok.. but you want the first element found that is after and not before right?  and you have those classes in the parent's sibling elements also?

Comment: i need to find the element with that class that is exactly after. it doesn't matter if its sibling of 'selectAfterThis' or sibling of his parents. or children of his sibling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separately add them into a collection.. then get the first out of the collection to find the closest one

```
// get siblings first - they will always be before parents
var ele = $('.selectAfterThis').nextAll('.OrMe');
// get parent siblings after current parent - they will be before their children
ele = ele.add($('.selectAfterThis').parent().nextAll('.OrMe'));
// get descendants that match of parent slibings
ele = ele.add($('.OrMe',$('.selectAfterThis').parent().nextAll()));
// now get first in collection
ele.first();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fRq4z/

Comment: @user1733078  Your welcome.  Wish there was an easier way :P.. If I think of one I will update my answer for you

Comment: about the last line. "get descendants that match of parent siblings" i dont quite get it ... can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Sure.. so from the starting point.. it goes to the parent element and gets all the siblings after the starting points parent... I used that as the context(Same thing as doing $(ancestor).find(selector)...  where the context is the ancestor element..  Then it just finds all the element that matches that are under that element